# ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError: Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :sender

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this working for other models, but can't seem to get it to work with the Notifications table (uses the Users model).

The error points to this line `count_of_males = Notification.joins(:sender).where(users: {gender: 'male'}).uniq.count`

I am determining from the Notifications table `sender_id` if the user is a male or female (from the User's table `gender` column ).

User model:

```
  def self.total_male
    count_of_males = Notification.joins(:sender).where(users: {gender: 'male'}).uniq.count
  end

  def self.total_female
    count_of_males = Notification.joins(:sender).where(users: {gender: 'female'}).uniq.count
  end
```

View:

```
    <%= User.total_male %> Dates by Males
    <P>
    <%= User.total_female %> Dates by Females
```

Comment: You'll need to post the relevant model classes and their relationships amongst one another.

Comment: @rossta User model `has_many :notifications`. There's no Notification model, since this is using the Mailboxer gem. Besides that, there is no relevant code from Users model that should be included to pull off what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to do a joins on `:sender` because it's a polymorphic association of your `Mailboxer::Notification`: https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/blob/master/app/models/mailboxer/notification.rb#L7

You could take a number of approaches, one of which is to use a SQL fragment for the join so you'll be able to pass in the additional conditions for the `users` table. Example:

```
join_clause = "INNER JOIN users ON notifications.sender_id = users.id AND notifications.sender_type = 'User'"
Notification.joins(join_clause).where(users: { gender: 'female' }).uniq.count
```

Comment: Thanks! You have been a big help